# How to redirect php pages to nuxt.js standard?

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a website made in php (which was first made in asp) so i redirected .asp webpages to .php in .htaccess file.

Now i am rebuilding the website using vue + nuxt.js and i am not finding how to do this again.

This time i need the .php or .asp pages to be without extension like:

```
/something/other/2.php
```

to

```
/something/other/2
```

404 redirects is not an option.. tried that my SEO dropped 90%.

I am pretty new to Vue and Nuxt so i'm kind lost here. How can this be done?

Comment: are you gonna deploy it on an VPS or on github pages, netifly?

Comment: Maybe in the future, for now on hostgator.

Answer (score -2):

for deploy purpose `nuxt.js` provides two methods:

1. universal
2. single page

if your server or host can run node and you can start node server upload all your files there and then run the code (it's probably runs on port 3000 so in your server config you need to redirect port 80 to 3000)

if you are on a static host go to your `nuxt.config.js` file and make shore that mode is `spa` and then run `npm run generate` and it makes a dist folder for you then copy all of data in dist folder to your host and use it like regular `html` and `js` files

Hope it helps you

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: you shouldn't redirect

.
when you use nuxt you use api calls
.

so just serve your  generated files and there is no .php or something else on it

Comment: People will try to go to .php pages.. i can't let them to a 404

Comment: This answer not corresponding the question.